# Require username+password after sleep/lock

Tags: password, touch-id

I want a command to force password input after sleep or manual lock with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> in High Sierra, as opposed to allowing TouchID alone to unlock the laptop.

### How?

#### Use case:

- You can be forced to supply your biometrics, but you can't be forced to supply your knowledge of a password, until mind-reading is a thing. Hence; when traveling, knowing that other people want to read/copy data contained on travelers' laptops, I want to secure my laptop by forcing authentication with username+password, as opposed to username+fingerprint.

Like for [iOS 11 but for macOS](https://www.theverge.com/2017/8/17/16161758/ios-11-touch-id-disable-emergency-services-lock).

#### Goal:

- Disable TouchID every time I want to force a password-based unlock, until the next time the laptop has been successfully unlocked.

#### Facts:

- I can lock the laptop and sign in with password if I click the avatar
- I can lock the laptop and unlock it with my fingerprint if I touch the Touch Id sensor.
- I have no way to force password on sign-in. That is what this question is about.

### Discourse:

There are two concepts in play here. What **principal** is trying to log in and what **credentials** versus **identification** that principal supplies. The principal in the above use-case is always myself, but TouchId does away with the **secret** part of the credential, and makes it so that authentication is successful by merely supplying a username—the fingerprint. In the triad, "*something you have*, *something you know*, *something you are*", it has replaced the "*something you know*" with "*something you are*". In the above threat-model, it has lessened security, because "*what you are*" is never possible for you to withhold.

Furthermore; because fingerprints are available on your phone, on the surface of your laptop, on your wallet, etc, I don't even "*have to be*", for the laptop to open, because they can be stolen or faked.

They are a fairly strongly identifying (one to two in a hundred people could share the same hash of the fingerprint); but they are not strongly authenticating. I want strong authentication using a secret ("what I know"), to be possible. That is what I'm asking for.

I hope this removes any doubts about what this question is asking.

#### Notes:

> You can't input commands after your computer is locked.

Sure I can; normally cabled ethernet is trusted: https://github.com/lgandx/Responder https://room362.com/post/2016/snagging-creds-from-locked-machines/ or a while back, now fixed: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207423

> ...if you could it would lessen security...

Not if the command can only strengthen security.

Besides, this is not what I'm asking about, I'm after a command for "strong lock machine", to enforce password-based authentication after sleep/lock/hibernate.

> This is a duplicate post

No, it's not.

> Typing is less secure since it can be observed and replicated

That is true for other threat modelling scenarios than I have as my use case. However, enabling 2FA (e.g. TouchId + password) for the laptop is a valid solution to this question, if it's possible.

Comment: Do not repost a closed question as new.  Original qustion:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/315679/revisions

Comment: It's not the same question. And you should have thought about that before you closed the other question, shouldn't you?

Comment: Typing a password is less secure.  Typing can be observed  and replicated.  Also, I don't understand the "use case".

Comment: @Tyson — I've addressed your feedback in the question. I've also answered the question; upvotes gladly accepted!

Comment: That use case is *very* weak.  Turn on FileVault disk encryption which **requires** a password.  Securing your laptop with nothing but user credentials does ***absolutely nothing*** to prevent "officials" from accessing your disk and data with/without your password.

Comment: @Allan That I have FileVault with encryption turned on goes without saying. I don't know where you confabulate your assumptions from, but it is neither my question nor my use case.

Answer (score 2):

1. After locking your laptop with Command+Control+Q, touch (don't depress) the Touch Id sensor five times with the wrong finger. Now Touch Id is temporarily disabled until you input your password.
2. Reboot the machine; now you must input your password.